# Playing Video on Mobile Phone while screen is off background

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I used video.js and video tag to play video in web browsers and it plays my video well. However, when web browser app goes background or i try changing tab, it stops video playback. Is there any tag or attributes or script i should use? I would take any replies with pleasure. Thank you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.3.0/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.3.0/video.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video
            id="my-player"
            class="video-js"
            data-setup="{}">
        <source src="[MY VIDEO LINK]" type="application/x-mpegURL"></source>
        </video>
        <script>
        videojs('my-player', {
        controls: true,
        autoplay: true,
        preload: 'auto',
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?